# Centering Multiple Objects at Zero When Instantiating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, formula

I am trying draw 'x' objects onto the screen where center of the container is the middle of all 'x' objects.

So, if I have a box where width=100 and height=100 and I want them to have a spacing of 100 and in this instance, x=5 (5 boxes), how do I get the boxes to start drawing at -450 to 450 with 0 being the center.

here is a picture of my example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAUTn.jpg)

(I'm using C# in Unity. I shortened a lot of stuff because I am more focused on the formula and less on the syntax of instantiating or the declaring of objects and values)

```
Object container = new Object();
Object box;

x = 5;

container.width = 1500;
container.height = 300;

box.width = 100;
box.height = 100;

int boxSpacing = 100;

int i = 0;
//normally, an if statement would work, but I need to use foreach other things
foreach (int number in x)
{
   Object newBox = Instantiate(box, new Vector2(0,0), Quaternion.identity, transform);
   newBox.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(getX(x), container.height / 2);
    
}

    float getX(int count)
    {
        return -1 * (count * box.width + (count - 1) * spacing) / 2 + (box.width / 2);
    }
```

I'm struggling with the formula for getX where (in this instance) I would start at -450 and end at 450. In fact, I think I am missing the mark all together. My plots either got all negative or all positive.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the formula, and from a starting x, I would add the space and the box width, passing in the `number` iterator, like so:

```
float startingX = -300; //chosen randomly for the example
float getX(int count, number)
{
    return startingX + number * (space + box.width);
}
```

With this each box x is 1 space + 1 box.widht to the right.
for number 0 -> startingX
for number 1 -> startingX + 1 space + 1 boxwith
for number 2 -> startingX + 2 space + 2 boxwith
.....and so on.

That logic meets the picture box distribution.